# Should user login and registration be separated from the principal menu items?

Tags: menu, login

My current layout looks like this:

```
LOGO         Sign up | Sign In        Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 | Item6 | Item7
```

Once user is logged, the user name appears with a drop-down option for modifying user profile.

```
LOGO                  R2D2 (156)      Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 | Item6 | Item7
```

I'm thinking that "Sign up" and "Sign in" is just to close to the principal menu items and maybe I should separate into two rows:

```
                                                                          Sign up | Sign In
LOGO                                  Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 | Item6 | Item7
```

Both rows are fixed and stay on top of the page when scrolled.

Comment: I'd go for the last aproach, since one bar is for navigation, while the other is for specific user data. I think most systems tend to do like that (even SE, as you can see); so people get used to it; next to fact that it logically makes sens to put it there, since its not navigation :-)

Answer (score 3):

A valid reason to do this is nowadays **tendency** to place user identification on the right side of the screen at least on medium and large screens.

Take a look at Facebook, Gmail, Twitter, Amazon, etc. All those place this items on the right, so the user will feel more confortable if you place them there too due to its **familiarity**.

Take into account that it's easier to scan items placed on the corners compared with the ones floating somewhere in the middle of the screen, so I would go for it.

As a side note, **it would be a very good idea to use different wording for the Login/Registrer actions**, since similar wording will produce bad effects both on native (maily slips) and even more in non-native english speakers. **[*Sign up/ Sign* wording is a bad practice](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-sign-up-and-sign-in-button-labels-confuse-users/)**.

Comment: User tests I ran a few months ago underlined the importance of placement. When the Login/Register links were placed in the upper-right corner of the screen more than 90% of test subjects found them. When moved elsewhere on the page, about 50% of users found the links. Why the upper-right corner? That's where convention has taught people to look for Login/Register.